# Scaling problem with CassandraDB structure

Tags: email, cassandra, bigdata, scaling

I'm trying to create a database based mail server. For this i choose to use CassandraDB. The main problem is: The more mail i have in my table, the longer the table answer (which is normal but scale to much). Currently i got like only 20000 mails and Cassandra send me a timeout (Set to 5secs by default apparently). The objective is to make every user find mail in my table containing more than 500k mails with the possibilities to filter their mails.

Here is my table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE mail__mail (
    accountid uuid,
    date timestamp,
    id uuid,
    attachment set<uuid>,
    categories set<uuid>,
    content text,
    dateadded timestamp,
    folderid uuid,
    hash text,
    isconfidential boolean,
    isdeleted boolean,
    isimportant boolean,
    isseen boolean,
    mailcc text,
    mailfrom text,
    mailid text,
    mailto text,
    size bigint,
    subject text,
    PRIMARY KEY (accountid, date, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC,id ASC);

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX mailFromIndex ON mail__mail (mailfrom) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS','analyzed': 'true', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX subjectIndex ON mail__mail (subject) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS','analyzed': 'true', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};
```

I'm pretty sure that my structure is bad due to my poor skills in CassandraDB.

Here are the operations i want to acheives with this table:

- UPDATE : isImportant, isConfidential, isDeleted, isSeen, mailId, folderId, categories
- DELETE : by id, by folderId, by accountId
- SELECT : by id, by folderId, by accountId

And i would like to select with this filter :

- ORDER BY : date, size, mailFrom (ASC and DESC)
- CONTAINS : categories (I can assign some categories to my mail, and i want to filter all email in one or more categories)
- LIKE '%*search*%' : mailFrom, subject to filter the mail containing my search
- Equals : isConfidential, isImportant, isDeleted, isSeen, to get all confidential, important, delete or seen mail.

My table works with few line in it (it works with 7k emails in 1000ms approximately) but i think it can be faster with the good structure and the good query (without the ALLOW FILTERING).

Moreover, i apparently can't use CONTAINS and LIKE '%*text*%' in the same query, it gave me a 1300 error code. So i did this step in python but in my opinion it's a performance disaster, it will be great if i can do everything with cassandra.

To query my CassandraDB i use Python3.5 Cassandra Driver but i don't think this information is relevant.

Tell me if you need more informations, 
thanks in advance !

EDIT : As a solution i follow what you guys told me, i deploy a new server with Elassandra (ElasticSeach + Cassandra). I will try to give you the result i get as soon as possible.

Comment: You need to take a step back on how you approach this. Do not model your data, model your queries. I would recommend going to DataStax academy and going through the data modeling classes as this project is very non trivial in Cassandra. You might be better off with another database. Avoid secondary indexes unless _absolutely necessary_ and do not use ALLOW FILTERING.

Comment: @Lohfink Thanks for your answer, i’m pretty sure it’s doable with a Cassandra database. But I’m really interested by your opinion about which database I should choose for this project. Anyway, everything on my project is based on Cassandra database and it will be hard for me to change now so my best option is to refactor my model and make it work.

Comment: "it will be hard for me to change now" - But it won't be nearly as hard as having to engineer Cassandra around your use case and ultimately change and move data later.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Lohfink suggestion about different view on modeling C* database, starting from the queries itself. But according to your requirements, the C* may be not be the perfect fit. You can redesign the schema in the following way:

- no queries with ALLOW FILTERING, as it does table scan.
- the same `mail__mail` schema, but with `id` and `date` merged to timeuuid to simplify things.
- instead of creating a ton of secondary indices (due to problems with high-cardinality data) and materialized views (because of data copying), you can use either external ElasticSearch or using it [as a plugin](https://www.elassandra.io/) for C* to perform the actual searches.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @shutty, you can use cassandra for your datastore along with ES for searching.